# HDInsight HDFS Fully Qualified URI

Tags: azure-hdinsight

As i see [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/fr-fr/documentation/articles/hdinsight-hadoop-use-blob-storage/) and [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/c6f3d63d-640f-49d0-877e-b555f68fba39/hdfs-architecture-of-hdinsight?forum=hdinsight) it should be possible to access HdInsight HDFS with something like

```
hdfs://<namenodehost>/<path>
```

but i'm not sure it's possible outside Azure, not sure of the port to use neither.

I'm actually trying with something like :

```
hdfs://hdinsightscopit.azurehdinsight.net:9000
```

Without success.

I need to access hdfs, i've no problem to connect with `wasb[s]://<containername>@<accountname>.blob.core.windows.net/<path>`

but it's not what i need.

Any idea ?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

HDInsight uses WASB instead of HDFS. This is an abstraction over Azure Blob Storage, so from outside the cluster you can just read/write directly to the blob to access the data.

For example, https://github.com/Blackmist/hdinsight-tools is a PowerShell script I created that allows you to enter WASB style addresses, but it just uses the standard Azure Storage Cmdlets to talk to storage.